# Reading from file -- awk

Tags: awk

I would like to read a file like this

```
1.23213213
0.12321321
-1.12321321
0.23232322
```

into a variable, or array to use it somewhere in the main {} code.
But I would like to use it if this file exists. How can I check if it already exists or not, and if not, then do not use that variable or array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand completely what you want to achieve, but perhaps something like this can be useful to you:

It process the file line by line and saves each one in an array, the key is the line number so you keep the order. In the `END` section check how many lines were processed and get if the file had content.

```
awk '{ line[ FNR ] = $0 } END { if ( FNR > 0 ) { print "File" } else { print "NO file" } }' infile
```

---

**EDIT** to comment:

But in `awk` you can process many files from command line.

```
BEGIN {
    ...
}

## Processing of first file in command line.
FNR == NR {
    a[ FNR ] = $0
    next
}

## Processing of second file in command line
FNR < NR {
    ## Check if array 'a' has the values you want and use them
    ## 'for(...)variable += a[i]' or whatever.
}
```

Run script like:

```
awk -f script.awk first_file.txt second_file.txt
```

But if `first_file.txt` doesn't exists, awk will complain with an error.

Comment: The original code is something like : BEGIN{...} {...} infile. But I want to use in the {...} part some constant numbers from another file. So far it looks like this: BEGIN{a[1]=1.23213213;a[2]=0.12321321;a[3]=-1.12321321;a[4]=0.23232322;} ... { ... for(...)variable += a[i]; ... }

Comment: I am thinking about something like, but I am not sure if it is a good way:  BEGIN { while( (getline x < "./some/infile" ) > 0 ) } {  ... for(...)variable+=x[i];  }

Comment: Hi, the code you have suggested does not work... Could there be a problem if I have this row before them: NR == 1 { ... } ?

Comment: @user1116360: It's legal and no problem, but why don't you explain the result to achieve and we can discuss about specific solutions?